# Custom paypal button as formbasics should show seller on paypal instead its shows logo/avatar

Tags: paypal

I have on my website for years a donate button installed, which also works great, however one thing bother me and hope someone can help me.

When click on the button and comes to Paypal, there is not the "company name" only a Avatar.

Source:
https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

Code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/de/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank" name="paypal">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" class="mail" value="seller@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="description" value="TEXT">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="12.34">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="returnPath(replaced)">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="notifyPath(replaced)">
<button type="submit">Donate with Paypal</button>
</form>
```

*Topic was previously called:
"Custom paypal button as formbasics should show seller on paypal instead its shows mail-adress"*
*A paypal employee verified my account as a business years ago and said he had upgraded it, which was obviously a false statement. I had now created an extra business account, which caused a similar problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your account to a PayPal Business account with the name you desire.

[Here is a PayPal support article](https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/how-do-i-change-the-type-of-paypal-account-i-have-help339), contact them for further details.

Comment: My account is (since years) already a business account. I have a "Merchant ID". ;)

Comment: Premier accounts also have merchant iDs. You need to include specific identifiers and resulting behavior in your question or contact PayPal for support.

Comment: You are right. Since I had verified my account with tax documents years ago and the statement of paypal was I am now business account, I thought so far I already have a business account. But the real business account looks quite different. If you do not know that .... ;) Thanks for point out.

Answer (score 0):

Official statement from paypal merchant technical support:

> Logos are a legacy feature, if one is specified and the checkout page
> is large enough to show things at the top, the logo image replaces the
> business name, so sometimes depending on the checkout e size of the
> screen, logo appears, and company name disappears but at background
> they both co exists.

You can't display avatar/logo and company name at the same time. In year 2023...

Comment: Logos are an old feature, most people use an in-context (JS SDK or donate SDK) flow now rather than redirecting away from their site to something large enough to show another logo. But if you do want to keep using an old redirect integration with a logo, it's expected that it be sufficiently identifying or include the business name as part of the logo image.